# Cant convert double to float c#, even thought using cast and no doubles in equasion. Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I was searching the internet for the answer and couldnt find it. I am extremely new, started 4 days ago.

I have some code to make the player rotate to where they moving, like in flappy bird, you know.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class PlayerAngle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        float x = transform.rotation.x;
        float y = transform.rotation.y;
        float xvel = (float)rb.velocity.x;
        float yvel = (float)rb.velocity.y;

        x = Math.Sin(yvel);
        y = Math.Sin(xvel);

        transform.Rotate(x, y, 0);
    }
}
```

It doesn't want to accept xvel and yvel which are supposed to be floats in Math.Sin.

Here is the exact error it gives me:

Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Please help me, I have spent hours trying to figure this out.

Thank you.

Comment: [Math.Sin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sin?view=netcore-3.1) returns double  which you are trying to assign to float variables `x` and `y`.

Comment: Guys i made it work Math.Sin actually accepts doubles so I just made everything use doubles Thanks Guru Stron

Answer (score 2):

One of the options is casting result of `Math.Sin` to float:

```
    x = (float)Math.Sin(yvel);
    y = (float)Math.Sin(xvel);
```

.NET [`Math.Sin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.sin?view=netcore-3.1) accepts and returns `double`, implicit conversion from `float` to `dobule` [exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#implicit-numeric-conversions) but in reverse you need to use explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use unity's `Mathf.Sin()` which returns a `float`

Comment: Or `System.MathF.Sin()`

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you there is no *implicit* conversion from a `double` to a `float`.

The reason for this is that the `double` type is a 64-bit (double-precision) number, and the `float` type is only a 32-bit (single precision) number, so there is the potential for a loss of precision when converting from `double` to `float`, and the authors didn't want that loss to happen "accidentally" during an assignment.

However, you can always *explicitly* cast the values to the correct type:

```
x = (float) Math.Sin(yvel);
y = (float) Math.Sin(xvel);
```

Or, better yet, just use `double` types all the way through:

```
void Update()
{
    double xVel = rb.velocity.x;
    double yVel = rb.velocity.y;

    double x = Math.Sin(yVel);
    double y = Math.Sin(xVel);

    transform.Rotate(x, y, 0);
}
```

Or, more precicely:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(Math.Sin(rb.velocity.y), Math.Sin(rb.velocity.x), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Unity related question, so we can assume that you were trying to use the **Mathf** static class. The System.Math class uses *double* by default.

Your code actually has a lot of extraneous operations. For example, you don't need to read the transform.rotation values.

With all that in mind, your updated code would look like:

```
void Update()
{
    var x = Mathf.Sin(rb.velocity.y);
    var y = Mathf.Sin(rb.velocity.x);
    transform.Rotate(x, y, 0);
}
```